# Refused to frame a PDF from AWS in Angular App

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, pdf, iframe

So i Have a weird problem in my Angular 11 app - I'm displaying a PDF to which I get a link from our AWS S3 bucket like this in a template:

```
<object [data]="pdfUrl | safeResource: 'resourceUrl'" class="pdf-preview" type="application/pdf">
    <p>This browser does not support PDFs.</p>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

On a localhost everything is working just fine and without errors, but a build version on a server shows error below:

```
Refused to frame 'here is a pdf link from S3' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'none'".
```

After refreshing a page with PDF it works like it should, problem occurs only on a first entry.

Our DevOps tried changing headers on the bucket and on a Angular app machine, but nothing seems to resolve this issue.

Have you ever experienced something like this? I'll apprecaite any help with this issue, thanks!

EDIT:
Here is how I assing pdf url in compopnent:

```
public get pdfUrl(): any {
    if (this._pdf === null || this._pdf.url === null) {
        return '';
    }
    return this._pdf.url;
}
```

And _pdf comes from a subscription fron DataContainer that send a GET to our API.

Comment: Could you please show the *.ts controller code for this component? How is the `pdfUrl` assigned?

Comment: Added the code above